# Creating a script to show a notification when updates are available

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to create a script to run with crontab where if any updates are available, the script will send a notification. The script itself isn't giving me any errors however in the if statement only the "else" part works. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update > ~/Desktop/UpdateInfo

update1=$(grep "package can be upgraded" ~/Desktop/UpdateInfo | cut -d' ' -f2,3,4,5)

var1="package can be upgraded."

if [ var1 = update1 ]
    then
        notify-send "Updates are available"
    else
        notify-send "test"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing the string `var1` to the string `update1`. Those will never be the same. You want to compare the variables instead:

```
if [ "$var1" = "$update1" ]
```

Of course, the entire thing could be simplified to:

```
sudo apt update | grep -q "package can be upgraded" && notify-send "Updates are available"
```

Answer (score 3):

On debian based distribution you can use the [`pk-update-icon`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/pk-update-icon) package:

> Displays an update-notification tray icon
>
> This small tool displays notifications and an icon in the tray area of the panel when package updates are available. It is primarily designed for desktops which do not already have this functionality integrated, such as Xfce.

```
apt install pk-update-icon
```

Schedule a cron job  (a brief delays is used for testing propose.) e,g:

```
crontab -e
```

past the following line:

```
*/1 * * * *  export DISPLAY=:0 ; /usr/bin/pk-update-icon -d 5 ; sleep 5 ; pkill pk-update-icon
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some code errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update > ~/Desktop/UpdateInfo

update1=$(grep "package can be upgraded" ~/Desktop/UpdateInfo | cut -d' ' -f2,3,4,5)

var1="package can be upgraded."

if [[ "$var1" == "$update1" ]]; then
    notify-send "Updates are available"
else
    notify-send "test"
fi
```

You need to use `$` to expand your variables.

You absolutely need to quote your variables when using the `[` test.  It's technically not needed in the `[[` test but you should quote anyway.